# Proving a graph with less than $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ edges is $k$-colorable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

We are to assume the graph has no loop edges.

I don't know where to begin this problem. I have tested small values of $k$ and it seems to hold up, but that isn't a proof. I have in my notes that $e \leq 3v-6$ where $v$ and $e$ are vertices and edges, respectively. So I tried this:

So I know $e < \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ and $e < 3v-6$, but I can't really do anything with this I don't think. The problem has a restriction on $e$ but not on $v$. Apparently that is important because my professor stressed that. Would it help if I wrote $v$ in terms of $k$? If there are less than $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ edges, then what can I say about the number of vertices?

I am hoping that I am on the right track here using this formula to solve this problem. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assume that the chromatic number of $G$ is equal to $k$. Can you prove that the graph must have atleast $\binom k2$ edges? **Hint:** Can you prove that for any pair of colors, say red and orange, some edge must join a red vertex to an orange vertex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We shall prove the contrapositive -  if a graph is not $k$-colorable, then it has at least $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ edges. Suppose that a graph $G$ has chromatic number $\chi(G)>k$.

Then for any pair of colors (under a $\chi(G)$-coloring), there must be an edge between two vertices of those colors (otherwise, you could merge both colors).
Since there are $\binom{\chi(G)}{2}$ such pairs, this implies that there must be at least $\binom{\chi(G)}{2} \geq \binom{k+1}{2}$ edges.

Thus, if there are less than $\binom{k+1}{2}$ edges, then $\chi(G)\leq k$ and the graph is $k$-colorable.